# Can't access attributes model backbone js

Tags: backbone.js

I am creating my "Hello world" app in backbone js. I am stuck at the very basic.

var gs = {
        documentRoot: ""
    }; // create namespace for our app

```
gs.Test = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: gs.documentRoot+'/test.php',
    initialize: function(){
        this.fetch();
    }
});

gs.TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
                    console.log(this.model);
        console.log(this.model.get('testId'));
    }
});

var testM = new gs.Test();

var test = new gs.TestView({model: testM});
test.render();
```

Here when I log model in the console, it shows fetched attributes from the server but I can't access those attributes from test.get('attribute'). I tried logging test.attributes, it gives empty object but when I log test, it shows those attributes in attributes object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` is async method, so you have to wait some time.
The best solution in this case is promises:

```
test.fetch().done(function() {
  console.log(test);
});
```

---

Your updated model:

```
initialize: function() {
  // save link to promise
  this.deferred = this.fetch();
}
```

And your render function:

```
render: function() {
  // use promise to render view after model will be fetched
  // use `bind` to save context of this view
  this.model.deferred.done(_.bind(function () {
    // model is fetched
    // all operations goes here
    console.log(this.model.get('testId')); // <- proper value
  }, this));
  console.log(this.model.get('testId')); // <- undefined
}
```

---

More about ajax you can read here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

```
var TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url : '/test.php'
});

var test = new TestModel();

// `context` context to be passed to any callback function
test.fetch({context:test}).done(function () {
  // `this` is equals to `test` (`context` option)

  // In case if you want to get all model data:
  // the best way to get model data for read-only mode.
  // this metod return a copy of the model's attributes
  console.log(this.toJSON());
  // you can also use `this.attributes` but this is not recommended
  console.log(this.attributes());      

  // In case if you want to get some model data:
  console.log(this.get('some_attribute'));   
  // If you want to get `c` from this model ({a:{b:{c:1}}}):
  console.log(this.get('a').b.c);    
});
```

Comment: I didn't see anyone implementing promises for simple backbone js apps. There should be an easy way to do it right? This is just start so you can tell me where further in application, I can access those attributes. I didn't write view code but I can't access attributes in it too.

Comment: Backbone uses jQuery ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax I'm going to update my answer with example

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to find a simpler solution but till then I will use this.:)

Answer (score 2):

`model#fetch` method has a `success` and `error` callback options that can be passed to fetch. The success callback gets called when the response from the server has come.

Right way to test the fetched attributes of a model is

```
test.fetch({
    success: function(model){
        // model here and test are same
        console.log(model);
        console.log(test.toJSON());
        // access your attribute with name `attributeName`
        console.log(test.get('attributeName'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are stuck with the same problem, here is the solution from the library itself.

Use model's in-built `'sync'` event to get the model attributes after `fetch()/save()` calls.

```
testM.on('sync',function(){
   test.render();
});
```